# TomcatとApacheの連携について

Tags: php, apache, tomcat

TomcatとApacheとの連携について、以下の条件の時はTomcatに転送しないようにする方法を考えております。

1 基本的にはtomcat側に転送する
　(例：http://hogehoge.com と入力されたらtomcat側に渡す)
2 例外的に特定のURLの時のみApache側で処理する
　(例：http://hogehoge.com/ownCloud/ と入力されたらApacheで処理する)

現在はmod_proxy_ajpを使って、ttp://hogehoge.com/と入力されたらすべてtomcat側に飛ばしています。

```
<Location / >
  ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/
</Location>
```

しかしこれではすべてtomcat側に転送されてしまってPHPで動くownCloudをApacheで処理できません。

最終目標としては、通常はtomcatのサイトをメインで使いつつ、ownCloudを導入したいと考えております。ですので、Tomcat上でownCloudを導入する方法などがあればご指南いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

これで/hogehoge/配下はapacheで処理されます。

```
# /hogehoge/ は 除外
ProxyPass /hogehoge/ !
<Location / >
  ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/
</Location>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。 無事、狙った挙動をさせることができました。
本当にありがとうございます！！